# Return a String value when boolean is true

Tags: java, boolean, return-value

I'm making some assignments and I've stumbled upon something I can't seem to fix.

So I made an enum class containing all the days of the week, and gave them a corresponding parameter to output the String value of the enums inside.

```
public enum Day{ Monday("monday");}
```

I then made the String to my enums final and made a constructor for it.

```
private final String day;

Day (String aDay) { this.day = aDay; }
```

Now I had to make a method that checks if it's a weekday or if it's a day in the weekend. I had to use a boolean for this.

```
    private boolean isWeekday() {
    if (this.getDay().equals("saturday") || this.getDay().equals("sunday")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now this part is where I'm struggling right now. I had to make a toString method that returns the day and if it's a weekday or not.

The output should be like this:

monday(weekday)
or
sunday(weekend)

My method "isWeekday" will obviously only return true's or false's at this point. How can I let it print out weekday when it's true and weekend when it's false?

```
    public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s(%s)", this.getDay(), ??;
}
```

Thanks in advance, I've tried searching Google but I haven't had any succes.

Comment: Use the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator (also called conditional operator):

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s(%s)", this.getDay(), isWeekDay() ? "(weekday)" : "(weekend)");
}
```

Relevant part:

```
isWeekDay() ? "(weekday)" : "(weekend)"
```

This basically results in

```
if(isWeekDay()) { 
    return "(weekday)";
} else {
    return "(weekend)";
}
```